# Uploading CSV for Impala

Tags: csv, hadoop, hue, impala

I am trying to upload the csv file on HDFS for Impala and failing many time. Not sure what is wrong here as I have followed the guide. And the csv is also on HDFS.

```
 CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE gc_imp 
                 (
                  asd INT,
                  full_name STRING,
                  sd_fd_date STRING,
                  ret INT,
                  ftyu INT,
                  qwerINT
                  ) 
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED FIELDS TERMINATED BY','
LOCATION '/user/hadoop/Gc_4';
```

Error which I am getting. And I am using Hue for it.

```
> TExecuteStatementResp(status=TStatus(errorCode=None,
> errorMessage='MetaException: hdfs://nameservice1/user/hadoop/Gc_4 is
> not a directory or unable to create one', sqlState='HY000',
> infoMessages=None, statusCode=3), operationHandle=None)
```

Any lead.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`/user/hadoop/Gc_4` must be a directory. So you need to create a directory, for example, `/user/hadoop/Gc_4`. Then you upload your `Gc_4` to it. So the file path is  `/user/hadoop/Gc_4/Gc_4`. After that, you can use `LOCATION` to specify the directory path `/user/hadoop/Gc_4`.

`LOCATION` must be a directory. This requirement is same in Hive and Impala.

Comment: I did it but it seems that my problem is still there. Is it because I am using Hue in comparison to shell commands.

Comment: Also does it matter if I am using extension csv. The docs suggests that it won't but I am suspicious.

Answer (score 1):

It's not the answer but a workaround.

In most cases I have seen that the table uploaded but the "status" was not successful. 
Also if you have stored the data with the help of Hive which gives you more control then "**Don't forget to REFRESH the metadata on Impala UI."** .Very Important.